# How to code a simple php5-fastcgi stdin stdout one time shot for now

Tags: php, stdin, fastcgi

I need someone to give me a sample code or some easy explanation on how to do cgi-fcgi to do stdin/stdout.  I did phpinfo() for my web host.  It says I am using php version 5.2.17.  I should probably up that to their 5.3 version as they say that is better. The info says there sapi is cgi/fastcgi.  Their loaded config file is /web/conf/php5.ini.  Their include_path is .:/usr/local/php5/lib/php.

I have been through loads of sites trying to figure out how to code stdin and stdout.  The code seems so simple but my problem likely has to do with proper coding of includes and other problems perhaps.  I have copied code from site examples and they don't work.  My web host is very little help.

I even started to change to a form with a php_self action but i changed my mind.  All I really need is someone's actual code example to use for an stdin and will build on that but I probably won't use it for anything but stdins and outs and maybe some error logs.

Please help me.  Thanks in advance!

Oldmanvette

Answer (score 0):

To work with stdin / stdout you have to deal with them like [files using the php:// wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

```
$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
```

and

```
$strout = fopen("php://stdout", "w");
```

Then you can use the normal file function (fgets, fread, fputs and fwrite etc...) to manipulate the values.

Comment: That's the real problem @Orangepill. I copied this code from php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-stream.php.  Then I copied code where I tried fgets($stdin,10) to no avail, ($stdin is file handle from fopen and field limited to 10 bytes). I have used the io-stream in the past for errlog but never communicated with the console and keyboard.  It just seems that there is something in a config or the php.ini file.  I assume that since the phpinfo shows loaded config as /web/conf/php5.ini it's not needed in my root dir. Please stick with me with advice.  Thank you.

Comment: I woke up about 5 am today thinking that maybe there could be a security setting that disallowed running the io stream.  I looked through security but did not identify anything that looked like a problem.  Any ideas all?